# Rendering data to a template and using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django

I have this form that collects data from a user. After the data has been entered I use HttpResponseRedirect
to protect from a refresh. The problem is since I am not using a database for this app,
I can't work out how to render the data the user has entered.

At the moment the data I need to be rendered is stored in cd. So how can I still redirect the user after sucessful
data entry and pass the data to another view, then render it? I can pass it to another class view, but rendering it is the problem,
as the data is passed by MathsConfig and not through urls.

Thanks, sorry I am new to Django.

code below

views.py

```
class MathsConfig(View):
    form_class = MathsForm
    initial={'operation': "Addition",
                     'rows': "",

                     "between1": "1 - 99",
                     "between2": "1 - 99",
                     "between3": None,
                     "between4": None,
                     "between5": None,

                     "questions": 20,
            }
    template_name = 'maths/maths-config.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('maths:maths_success'))
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class MathsQuestions(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # want to pass cd varible here and then render it.

class MathsSuccess(TemplateView):
    template_name = "maths/maths-success.html"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^config/$', views.MathsConfig.as_view(), name='maths_config'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.MathsSuccess.as_view(), name='maths_success'),
    url(r'^$', views.MathsQuestions(), name='maths_display'),
)
```

Edit:

```
class MathsQuestions(Object):

    def __init__(self, request):

        if 'entered_form_data' in request.session.keys():
            formdata = request.session['entered_form_data']
            del request.session['entered_form_data']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in session.

```
request.session['entered_form_data'] = data
```

And in next view:

```
if 'entered_form_data' in request.session.keys():
    formdata = request.session['entered_form_data']
    del request.session['entered_form_data']
```

**Edit:**

```
def someview(request):
  template = 'something.html'

  form = SomeForm(request.POST) if request.method == 'POST' else SomeForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
      data = form.get_cleaned_data()
      request.session['entered_form_data'] = data
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/someurl/')

  render_to_response(template, {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def someurl_view(request):
  template = 'someurl.html'

  render_to_response(template, {'formdata':request.session.pop('entered_form_data', None)}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and of course you need to create the function, that returns data from form yourself. I mean the function which i refer to as form.get_cleaned_data(). Do it whichever way you want although i suggest you return dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to add this but I get a type error. Again I am new to Django and not sure of the correct syntax.      See edit above for what I tried.

Comment: You need to do data storing in view,  not in form. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb your second snippet could be completely replaced with just `formdata = request.session.pop('entered_form_data', None)`
`

Comment: Right you are. As this user is pretty new to django/python those shorthands/shortcuts might confuse him though :)